# Is there a (introductory) differential equations books from the infinitesimal perspective?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonstandard-analysis

I am aware that there are books treating calculus solely from the infinitesimal perpective.  Are there books doing the same for ordinary/partial differential equations?  I would be interested in introductory to advanced books - if such books exist.

Answer (score 2):

*Nonstandard analysis, a practical guide with applications* by Lutz and Goze, (Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics #881) has a large section (150 pages) on perturbation analysis.

*Nonstandard analysis* by Robert (Dover publications) has about 15 pages on DEs and Green functions.

...but I don't know any text completely devoted to nonstandard methods for DEs.

Answer (score 1):

Keisler's *Foundations of Infinitesimal Calculus* has a chapter (chapter 14) on differential equations, at http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/foundations.html